# Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's "panties"?

Tags: dc, costume, wonder-woman, clothing

In [Epic Rap Battles of History: Wonder Woman vs Stevie Wonder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7jL0NJ98Nc), Stevie Wonder (played by T-Pain) concludes his first verse with

> I'm the ceremony master blaster with the bars
>
> And I got more Grammies than your panties got stars

[Stevie Wonder has won 25 Grammy awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevie_Wonder#Grammy_Awards) as of this writing. He has also won a Grammy Lifetime Achievement Award, but we shall ignore that in the count.

Is there any official incarnation or illustration of Wonder Woman that has had 25 or more stars on her panties, which would make this claim incorrect? Perhaps one with a very small star print?

Comment: The canonical term from the [theme song](http://www.lyricsondemand.com/tvthemes/wonderwomanlyrics.html) is "satin tights".

Comment: Can I just point out that "panties" means underwear.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on **https://skeptics.stackexchange.com**?

Comment: Awesome question.  Not their best work, but props goes to the match up.

Comment: Outstanding question by the way  :)

Comment: [Meta regarding this question's title](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/i-see-britain-i-see-france-i-see-wonder-womans-satin-tights)

Comment: In accordance with the 12-0 vote on [the meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/i-see-britain-i-see-france-i-see-wonder-womans-satin-tights), I'm going to take the honour of editing the original question.    Please **do not revert or modify** the title.   If you have a beef, take it to the meta.

Comment: To format poetry without the ugly hack of double-spacing the lines (or the even worse ugly hack of using code formatting), simply put two spaces at the end of each line of text.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Assuming you always count the swimsuit-style bottom as "panties", then, yes, on at least one cover (Wonder Woman #63 from 1992), Wonder Woman has not only had more than 25 stars, she's has more than 25 stars visible from the FRONT.

[image]

Comment: In other words, Stevie Wonder is clearly blind. Oh, wait...

Comment: @Machavity: Funnily enough, that's a matter of some controversy. According to some reports, he is legally blind, but not completely blind, although he claims the latter for convenience.

Comment: HER HAIR IS EVERYTHING I WANT TO BE WHEN I GROW UP

Answer (score 46):

Lynda Carter's costume from the 1970s [*Wonder Woman/The New Adventures of Wonder Woman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(TV_series)) had at least that many stars:

[image: Lynda Carter as Wonder Woman]

Comment: Might want to mention where Lynda Carter's costume is from. Did she play Wonder Woman in a TV show?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes, she did. Link added to answer.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro you didn’t know that?  You *must* rent the complete series now!

Comment: "the greatest superhero TV show of all time" - Citation needed

Comment: @TylerH See image.

Comment: @KSmarts What image?

Comment: The more I look at the shape of those ‘panties’ (for lack of a better term), the less natural her waist and legs look. How the hell did they manage to give her that bizarre shape?!?

Answer (score 22):

Aaah, the much awaited question about Wonder Woman!

### DCAU

Certainly less:

#### [Justice League Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series)): **6**

Going by symmetry, the count should be 6 or at max 7.

[image: Wonder Woman in JLAS] [image: Wonder Woman in JLAS]

#### [Wonder Woman (2009 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(2009_film)):  **16-17**

6 on front side, 10 on the back side

[image: Wonder Woman front side]  [image: Wonder Woman backside]

#### [Justice League Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_Doom) : **10**

[image: Wonder Woman fighting Cheetah]

#### [Justice League War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies#Justice_League:_War) : **2**

[image: Wonder Woman side view]

Conclusion:  less than 25.

---

### Comics: it actually varies from an unknown quantity:

[image: Wonder Woman in DC new 52]

to **over 25**.

[image: Wonder Woman in comics]

More images at [Wonder Woman wiki](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman).

Comment: To complete your set of animated TV shows, I Google Image searched ["wonder woman young justice"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wonder+woman+young+justice&tbm=isch).  Verdict: ~8-10 stars, way less than 25.  Note that YJ is not in the same continuity as the DCAU.