# What do the stars on Wonder Woman's outfit represent?

Tags: dc, history-of, wonder-woman, costume

After reading about the [hubbub](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11010/75000) over [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161177/75000), I started to wonder what the stars on Wonder Woman's outfit even stand for. Out if universe I'm assuming they have something to do with her being an American-made hero, but I want the in-universe explanation. I think I read somewhere that she crafted her original costume from an American flag she found, but I can't recall where I saw this.

I couldn't find anything on her [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman) or her [Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)) page talking about the meaning behind the design. She was a member of the Star Sapphire Corps, but that was apparently very short lived and I'm unsure of her connection to this group prior to this instance, and their star design differs from WW's, so that might not have affected her look.

**So what do the stars on Wonder Woman's outfit represent?**

### WW:

[image]
[image]

### Star Sapphires:

[image]

Comment: You're asking about Wonder Woman but include Star Sapphire as well? Regarding the stars, I seem to remember her outfit being a gesture of good will to the country she's going to (i.e. it's supposed to resemble the American flag).

Comment: @Gallifreyan I added them to compare their star design to WW's

Comment: I also remember either a comic or animated movie that mentioned the rare times the amazonians left their island they would wear an outfit that was "respectful/ honoring" of whatever the host nation was. Given the american flag I would assume that stars would have been a simple and easy addition. Im not sure where that would fall in the lore (especially since i cant remember where i heard it), but fyi...

Comment: These were Captain America's pants originally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the comics:

The golden age (Earth-2) and silver age (Earth-1) versions of Wonder Woman provided no in-universe explanation of the similarity between her costume and the US flag (same colors, same color scheme (plus gold), white stars on a blue field).

In the (basically) rebooted universe following *Crisis on Infinite Earths*, Wonder Woman was reintroduced, and some explanation was given. In *Wonder Woman* #12 (Vol.2, Jan 1988), we find out that a female air force pilot (circa WWII) crashed on Paradise Island many years ago, and died helping the Amazons in battle. The costume was based on her "standard" (the US flag). She turned out to be Diana Trevor, mother of Steve Trevor (who at least looked like a middle-aged man in this incarnation, and I can't recall being presented as a love interest of any note). And Diana, Wonder Woman, is named for her.

Hippolyta had the Amazons create two sets of battle armor; Diana T. was cremated with one set, the other was saved, and eventually given to - Diana.

Not sure if that survived into the New 52 version (I doubt it, as Steve is back to being a younger possible love interest for Diana).

Comment: Who actually made the costume based on the pilot's standard?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Hippolyta ordered it made/forged - beyond that, no specifics are given. Answer updated with same.