# Are there any stars at all on Wonder Woman's costume (or other Themysceriana) in the 2017 film?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, costume, wonder-woman-2017

There has been some recent debate regarding stars on Wonder Woman's outfit:

[Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's "panties"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161177/have-there-ever-been-25-or-more-stars-on-wonder-womans-panties)

There has also been some buzz that "Wonder Woman is [not American enough](http://ew.com/movies/2017/06/02/fox-news-wonder-woman-not-american-enough/)" from certain unsurprising sources.

So, were there actually any stars or allusions to stars in the 2017 *Woman Woman* film?

(Of course actual American flags or other period objects don't count unless an argument can be made they are intentional references.)

Comment: Does the one on her headpiece count?

Comment: @Valorum, why wouldn't it?

Comment: It's on her crown rather than her outfit.

Comment: @Valorum, both the question in the title and the question in the body clearly include it.

Comment: I didn't think it was all that clear,  which is why I asked.

Comment: @Valorum:   *costume* includes anything she wears; *Themysceriana* includes anything of Themyscerian origin; *stars or allusions to stars in the film* includes pretty much anything.   That is ranging for somewhat narrow to extremely broad, and the headpiece clearly fits into all three.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whilst not five pointed, there's a prominent star on Diana's inherited head piece.

[image: eight pointed star]

In Babylonian symbolism, the goddess Ishtar is represented by an eight-pointed starburst and she is associated with the planet of Venus.

The Romans equated Aphrodite with Venus and, today, some people equate the Greek Goddess Aphrodite with Ishtar. Both goddesses represent lust and sexuality, although Ishtar also represents fertility and war.

In an interview with the Hollywood Reporter, costume designer Michael Wilkinson expands on his choice regarding the star:

> The tiara was an interesting challenge. We thought, there’s something
>   sort of girly and princess-y about the word "tiara," so we thought we
>   should use the word "headdress," which sounds much more tough and
>   warrior-like. So, for the headdress, traditionally it’s been a classic
>   five-pointed red star. I looked more into her legacy and I chose a
>   gold pointed star, based on an iconic Greek star. I thought that would
>   be appropriate knowing her background, and so I created a different
>   shape for the star. Of course there’s all sorts of things she has such
>   as the eagle and WW motif throughout the costume, so I tried to use
>   that WW motif through the belt and the gauntlets and across the
>   breastplate. There’s WW throughout the costume. I think someone tried
>   to count them and they got to 40.

The pentagram itself is not uniquely American and is a common ideogram used throughout the world. The use of a five pointed star originates from European or Western heraldry, and the golden five-pointed star has associations with military power and war.

[image]

Comment: Wow,  I actually thought the answer was going to be *no*,  so thanks for providing an answer that is both surprising and meaty.

Answer (score 0):

I am yet to see the Wonder Woman movie, so I can't comment on any allusions, but in regards to her costume, the answer is apparently no; Wonder Woman's 'panties' (or any other piece of her clothing for that matter) do not bare stars.

In fact, it appears that her 'panties' in general have been removed in lieu of a plate skirt.

[image]

Comment: @jaepage "Plaited" means braided... "plated" presumably means "made out of plate metal"?

Comment: He asks about her costume, not exclusively her bottoms, why have you felt the need to purely address her bottoms?

Comment: @Edlothiad, well, let's be fair.  The bottoms are the locations the stars in the other canons.  So while your point is right, I don't think the rhetorical question was necessary because the answer to it is obvious.

Comment: @edlothaid - because thats where the stars originally were. If stars were elsewhere I would have mentioned, but, since they are not elsewhere, I thought any mention of other clothing would be inane.

Comment: Since we're nitpicking anyway, "bare" or "bear"? This sounds like a bit of a Freudian slip.

Comment: @MrLister especially when combined with "removed" instead of "replaced"